# Not being able to print an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i created empty array using the React State Hook, the array starts empty and i have 3 functions to (add to the array), (remove the last element of the array) and another to empty the array. The functions seems to work since i logged the result in the console. But when i want to print the array on a paragraph, the array does not show. Can someone give me some feedback?  Thanks.

The code is below

```html
import './counter.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function HandleArray() {
  const [inicial, handler] = useState([]);

  function addElement(element) {
    inicial.push('ok');
    handler(inicial);
    console.log(inicial);
  }
  function removeElement() {
    inicial.pop();
    handler(inicial);
    console.log(inicial);
  }
  function reset() {
    inicial.length = 0;
    handler(inicial);
    console.log(inicial);
  }

  return (
    <div className='card text-bg-light border-success mb-3'>
      <div className='card-header'>Welcome</div>
      <div className='card-body'>
        <h5 className='card-title'>Manipulate the array</h5>
        <button type='button' className='btn btn-dark ' onClick={addElement}>
          Insert Element
        </button>
        <button
          type='button'
          className='btn btn-danger'
          onClick={removeElement}
        >
          Remove Element
        </button>
        <button type='button' className='btn btn-warning' onClick={reset}>
          Reset array
        </button>
        
        
        //log the array 
        
        <p className='card-text'>{inicial}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, you shouldn't mutate state. Mutating state is an anti-pattern, not allowed, a big no-no (hope I was clear on this one). What you do, is you create a copy of your state, and call the handler with this new value.

For example:

```
function addElement(element) {
  inicial.push('ok');
  handler(inicial);
  console.log(inicial);
}
```

Should be:

```
function addElement(element) {
  const inicialCopy = [...inicial] //using spread operator to create a new array. You can create a new array using new Array, or any other way.
  inicialCopy.push(element)
  handler(inicialCopy)
}
```

This way, `handler` was called with a new entity (a new array) so we are ok to go. There are other ways to do this. Let's do the next one using a callback.

```
function removeElement() {
  handler((prevState)=>{
    prevState.pop() // prevState now has 1 less element
    return prevState
  });
}
```

Same principle. You call `handler` to update the new value.

Lastly, reset could just call `handler` with an empty array.

```
function reset() {
  handler([]);
}
```

Now, let's speak about two other issues.
The first one is naming. When you use the useState hook, by convention, the naming would be something like this:

```
const [property, setProperty] = useState(initialValue)// which in your case:
const [initial, setInitial] = useState([])
```

Lastly, you placed `console.logs` inside your functions. Those console.logs will log the OLD state. Not the new one.

If you want to have the new one, you need to wrap it in a `useEffect`, and add `inicial` to the dependencies array:

```
useEffect(()=> { console.log(inicial)}, [inicial]}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. New to programming so i really appreciate your answers !